Amend the script to "import in-cell images" as well along with the data+formulas
So I've been using this existing script found on docs community forum to copy data and formulas from the source to target. Its working all good but the only hiccup is it fails/halts at the point the script encounters a cell with an in-cell image.

Also the images are embedded directly into the cells at source(Insert>Image>Insert image in cell) and not by the image function

function copyFormulasAndValues() {
  const rangeA1 = 'C4:D31';
  const sourceRange = SpreadsheetApp
    .openById('1B_tK9FP8q1Cs1Cuqv7xWq5QSsBbRLY-k-nhxUhv4H7k')
    .getRange('Sheet1!' + rangeA1);
  const targetRange = SpreadsheetApp
    .getActive()
    .getRange('Sheet1!' + rangeA1);
  const values = sourceRange.getValues();
  sourceRange.getFormulas().map(function (row, rowIndex) {
    row.map(function (formula, columnIndex) {
      if (formula) {
        values[rowIndex][columnIndex] = formula;
      }
    });
  });
  targetRange.setValues(values);
}

Hoping someone could modify the script to include the in-cell images as well to be copy and pasted along with the data+formulas.

Issue and workaround:
I confirmed the same situation with you. I'm worried that in the current stage, the CellImage object retrieved by getValues might not be able to be directly put into cells by setValues. So, in this answer, as a workaround, I would like to propose using a Google Apps Script library I created. When this is reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.
Usage:
1. Install a library
Please install a library DocsServiceApp. You can see how to install it here.
2. Modified script
In this modification, the images in the cells are retrieved as Blob using a library DocsServiceApp. And, the CellImage object is created using the retrieved Blob. And then, the created CellImage object is put into cells using setValues.
function copyFormulasAndValues() {
  const rangeA1 = 'C4:D31';
  const sourceRange = SpreadsheetApp
    .openById('1B_tK9FP8q1Cs1Cuqv7xWq5QSsBbRLY-k-nhxUhv4H7k')
    .getRange('Sheet1!' + rangeA1);
  const targetRange = SpreadsheetApp
    .getActive()
    .getRange('Sheet1!' + rangeA1);

  // --- I added the below script.
  const sheet = sourceRange.getSheet();
  const obj = DocsServiceApp.openBySpreadsheetId(sheet.getParent().getId()).getSheetByName(sheet.getSheetName()).getImages();
  // ---

  const values = sourceRange.getValues();
  sourceRange.getFormulas().map(function (row, rowIndex) {
    row.map(function (formula, columnIndex) {
      if (formula) {
        values[rowIndex][columnIndex] = formula;

      // --- I added the below script.
      } else if (values[rowIndex][columnIndex].valueType == SpreadsheetApp.ValueType.IMAGE) {
        const rowOffset = sourceRange.getRow();
        const colOffset = sourceRange.getColumn();
        const o = obj.find(({ range: { row, col } }) => row == rowIndex + rowOffset && col == columnIndex + colOffset);
        if (o) {
          values[rowIndex][columnIndex] = SpreadsheetApp.newCellImage().setSourceUrl(`data:${o.image.blob.getContentType()};base64,${Utilities.base64Encode(o.image.blob.getBytes())}`).build();
        } else {
          values[rowIndex][columnIndex] = null;
        }
      }
      // ---

    });
  });
  targetRange.setValues(values);
}


When I tested this script, I confirmed that the values, formulas, and images in the cells could be copied.

Reference:

DocsServiceApp (Author: me)


Tested and working perfect. Thanks for your valuable time. Sorry I could not upvote since me being a new user!

@love_boring_ Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About Sorry I could not upvote since me being a new user!, it's no problem. Thank you, too.
